# Why is my form data being split into 2 post request?

Tags: javascript, forms, node.js, post, sails.js

I have a form with 3 text input fields and 1 file input field. When I use the following script to post the data to server:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(event){

    var product_name          = $("#product_name").val(),
        product_price         = $("#product_price").val(),
        product_description   = $("#product_description").val(),
        product_image         = $("#product_image").val();

    if ( product_name && product_price ) { 
        $.post(
            '/product/create',
            { product_name: product_name,
              product_price: product_price,
              product_description: product_description,
              product_image: product_image
              }   
        ).fail(function(res){
            alert("Error: " + res.getResponseHeader("error"));
        }); 
    } else {
      if ( ! $("#form_err").length )
      {   
        showErrorAlert("Please fill product name and price.");
      }   
      return false;
    }   
});
```

and having the following server JS script:

```
 create: function(req, res) {
    var product_name = req.param("product_name"),
        product_price = req.param("product_price"),
        product_description = req.param("product_description"),
        product_image = req.param("product_image");

    console.log("product_name: " + product_name);
    console.log("product_price: " + product_price);
    console.log("product_description: " + product_description);
    console.log("product_image: " + product_image);

    if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        if(req.files) console.log(util.inspect(req.files));
        if(req.file) console.log(util.inspect(req.file));
        if(req.body) console.log(util.inspect(req.body));
        return res.view({
          layout: "layout",
          product_name: product_name});
    } 
  }
```

My form data is being split into 2 POST requests as shown in the log (first with text fields data and second one with file input data) :

```
product_name: 9iiouiouoiu
product_price: 9.00
product_description: lijlijij
product_image: undefined
{ product_name: '9iiouiouoiu',
  product_price: '9.00',
  product_description: 'lijlijij' }
product_name: undefined
product_price: undefined
product_description: undefined
product_image: czarne_lampki.jpg
{ product_image: 'dots.jpg' }
```

Why does it happen like this ?

**EDIT**

After adding 
    event.preventDefault();

I get the following - without redirection to desired page `product/create`

```
product_name: pro
product_price: 88.00
product_description: wsad
product_image: undefined

body 
{ product_name: 'pro',
  product_price: '88.00',
  product_description: 'wsad' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click submit triggers the post of the form elements, on top you are adding the data to an object in your post.

Either you need to add in your click handler:

```
 event.preventDefault();
```

Or you need to remove the custom object you create on post since all your form elements are already automatically posted.

Comment: You should handle the form with validat/submit, not click/post

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I couldn't get the filename from the `<input type="file">` form. Instead I have used `event.target.files` as follows:

```
$(function(){
    var file,
        product_image_name,
        product_image_size;

    $('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);

    // Grab the files and set them to our variable
    function prepareUpload(event)
    {
      file = event.target.files[0];
      product_image_name = file.name;
      product_image_size = file.size;
    }

    $("#form_new_product").submit(function(event){

        var product_name          = $("#product_name").val(),
            product_price         = $("#product_price").val(),
            product_description   = $("#product_description").val();

        if ( product_name && product_price ) {
            $.post(
                '/product/create',
                { product_name: product_name,
                  product_price: product_price,
                  product_description: product_description,
                  product_image_name: product_image_name,
                  product_image_size: product_image_size
                  })
            .fail(function(res){
                alert("Error: " + res.getResponseHeader("error"));
                })
            .done(function(res){
                showInfoAlert("Product : \"" + product_name + "\" has been added to catalog.");
                });
          return false;
        } else {
          if ( ! $("#form_err").length )
          {
            showErrorAlert("Please fill product name and price.");
          }
          return false;
        }
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```